# pytorch forward passing data from convolutional layers to GRU layers

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, layer

i am new to pytorch and i am trying to pass a 2-dimentional matrix through a Conv1d layer (process each line seperatly), then pass it through a GRU layer. i know that the output shape of the conv1d layer is (N, C, L) which i assume is (batch_size, features_dimension, sequence_length).
And the input shape of the GRU layer is (L, N, H) which i assume is (sequence_length, batch_size, features_dimension).
can someone please provide me some code assuming that the input matrix is [32,300,50] which is (batch_size, sequence_length, features_dimension)

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
x = torch.rand(32,50,300) #32:batch_size , 50:features_dimension , 300:sequence_length
conv1 = nn.Conv1d(50, 40, kernel_size=5, stride=2) #from 50 dimension to 40 channels
conv2 = nn.Conv1d(40, 30, kernel_size=3, stride=1) #from 40 dimension to 30 channels
act = nn.ReLU()
pool = nn.MaxPool1d(2, stride=2)
#convolutional layers dimensions
conv_out1 = ((x.shape[1]-5)//2 +1)//2
conv_out2 = ((conv_out1-3)+1)//2
gru = nn.GRU(30, 20, 10)
out1 = pool(act(conv1(x))) #result shape [32,40,74]
out2 = pool(act(conv2(out1))) #result shape [32,30,36]
out3 = out2.permute(2,0,1) #result shape [36,32,30]
out4,_ = gru(out3) #result shape [36,32,20]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i provided the code, i just need to know if its correct to use the layer in such a way to train a classification model or not

Comment: You could try using torch.view(https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html) to reshape your input and then pass it through your neural network.